# Query the soil map and data by polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to query the soil data via https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx.

Input is the polygon coordinates.
Result: features (polygon), key, soil code, soil name, total acres, % of field, PI ...

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try any of the options in the help file,

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the WMS

> https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDM.wms?

You can see what the service will give by doing a GetCapabilities response:

[GetCapabilities response](https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDM.wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities)

In ArcMap select Add Data > Add WMS Server.

For the URL give `https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDM.wms?`

For version select `1.1.1`

Click OK (to all prompts to take the default settings)

Then select the layers you want to view on your map.

Use the query tool to view attribute values at any point location.